# Alias "yii.swiftmailer" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file

Tags: php, yii, yii2, swiftmailer, yii-extensions

I have configure yii2-swiftmailer according to documentation but when I send the mail then showing this error:

> Alias "yii.swiftmailer" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\protected\controllers\HomeController.php(250)
246 
247     public function actionMail()
248     {
249 
250         Yii::app()->mailer->compose()
251             ->setTo('example@gmail.com')
252             ->setFrom('example2@gmail.com')
253             ->setSubject('Invite')
254             ->setTextBody('Hello!')
255             ->send();
256 
257     }
258 }
```

And my extension folder...
extention\yii2-swiftmailer

and my config:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
            //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you try to use swiftmailer for yii2 not version 1. Try another extension dedicated completely for yii first version http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swiftmailer/